# MVC - Refresh View Model asynchronously via AJAX + Controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I've been working on filtering a list of log entries, and I'm getting close to being complete.

I'm wondering if it's possible to update the current View's model asynchronously via `$.ajax()`.

I currently have the `$.ajax()` working, however it returns the entire page's HTML as opposed to a partial view, or a model itself.

Is anybody aware of a way to simply update the model on the current view?

Comment: If you return a model, you JS will have no idea how to put that into HTML.

Comment: You'd have to return the model in json format and use js templating functionality to replace the server rendered html in the dom.

Comment: Show some code! You can make some logic returning the last result as JSON and using ajax append this result to the page! But you will need some JavaScript logic to do this as @SLaks said!

Comment: Note that you can use things like Knockout to tell the JS how to update the HTML (client-side ViewModel binding).  You can make server-side helpers that insert the current model value and a Knockout bind attr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You'd have to return the model in json format and use js templating
>   functionality to replace the server rendered html in the dom. –
>   WestDiscGolf

The above is the solution, so I'll keep it simple and use a more conventional method.

Answer (score 1):

This concept doesn't really make sense. The model doesn't really exist any more once the page is rendered, until it is reinstantiated on the following POST (assuming it *is* reinstantiated, i.e. your controller action accepts an argument of the same type). In the meantime, it is just manifested as form fields with `name` properties that correspond to what *were* the model's properties.

You can, however, dynamically create form fields that will (if possible) be mapped back to model properties again when the form is posted.

Create a field, whose `name` property matches the name of your model property:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnMyProperty" name="MyProperty" />
```

Then use jQuery to populate the field's value:

```
var property = /* Your returned value here */;
$('#hdnMyProperty').val(property);
```

There are a couple of common ways of achieving this:

1. Make an AJAX request to a controller action that returns a `JsonResult` and dynamically create the form field(s) in your Javascript (potentially - as has been mentioned - utilizing something like Knockout).
2. Create a controller action that returns a `PartialViewResult` and dynamically insert the returned markup in the appropriate place.

When you issue the next post request, the model binder will try to map this to an appropriate property in the newly-instantiated model.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). No need to re-invent the wheel in this case.